# Output to Time to File Multiple Times in C++ by Running Program Multiple Times

Tags: c++, xcode

I want to output the time it takes my C++ program to run to a file on my desktop called C10.txt. I want to run the program 100 times and then when I open the file, it tells me all of the different times that the program took to run. I know I need fstream to do this, but I have no clue where to go from there. Here is the code I want to run multiple times. What should I add to it to make this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int*,int,int);
void mergeSort(int*,int,int);


const int ARRAYSIZE = 10;

int main()
{

    clock_t startTime = clock();
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));

    cout << (double( clock() - startTime ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000000<<  " microseconds." << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In main(), create an `ofstream yournamehere ("path_to_desktop\C10.txt");` before you actually do anything.

Then just call your code in a for loop, assigning `clock()` to startTime at the beginning and writing what you're writing now to `cout` to `yournamehere` instead.

Comment: First off, thank you for your help! Second, Using the code above, I can now add the time to the C10.txt document, but each time I run the program, the time in the C10.txt document changes. I want that each time I run the program, the new time just gets added to C10.txt document

Comment: `ofstream yournamehere ("path_to_desktop\C10.txt", ios::app);` it is, then.

Answer (score 0):

Open an ofstream in append mode.
`std::ofstream tlog("C10.txt", std::ofstream::app);`.
In main, write clock records to `tlog` instead of `std::cout`.

Your use of `std::endl` is wasteful. Endl flushes the stream, and it doesn't sound like you need that. Just use a newline "\n" directly.